# Why am I receiving a TypeError of Cannot read property 'move' of undefined for an array and object I have defined?

Tags: javascript, typeerror

Receiving TypeError: Cannot read property 'move' of undefined
    at fitnessTest.

```
function fitnessTest(arrayObject){
  let turnsArray = [];
  for (i = 0; i <= arrayObject.length; i++){
    let steps = 0;
    let turns = 0;
    while (steps <= 20){
      steps += arrayObject[i].move();
      turns++;
    } turnsArray.push(`${arrayObject[i].name} took ${turns} turns to take 20 steps.` );
  }      return turnsArray;
}
```

the .move property is defined inside an object as

```
    move: function(){
      return Math.round(Math.random()*10);
```

and that object is placed inside of an array passed to the fitnessTest function

Comment: `i` must be smaller than the array length: `for (i = 0; i < arrayObject.length; i++){`
You are iterating over the size of the array and the last element in your for loop is undefined

Comment: Thank you! This was all it was. Always something simple it seems.